# PHP Function and method change if Using PHPfmt in sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using sublime editor 3 for php and install Package PHPfmt for psr2.

And my PHP version is 5.6.

After save my php code PHPfmt change my php function like

my function is:

```
<?php

function test_demo(){
  echo "hello";
}
```

After save

```
<?php
    function testDemo(){
       echo "hello";
    }
```

How to stop this but not removing phpfmt please suggest aleternate of phpfmt or how can i get rid of this;